# ArcMap field calculator expression failing with ERROR 000539

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser, error-000539

I am using ArcMap 10.7.

I have an attribute table with 6 different columns of short integer data.  These columns store the birth day, birth month, and birth year, as well as the death day, death month, and death year of interred individuals.  I  want to calculate the age of the interred so I found this Python code (below) to accomplish this task. The test code will return the Julian date from the day, month, year.  Then I subtract the two Julian dates and divide by 365 to get the age (in decimal years) of the interred.

I can confirm that this code works in my Python IDE.  I can confirm that arcpy includes the pandas library.

```
import pandas
def get_julian(mm,dd,yyyy):
    ts = pandas.Timestamp(year = yyyy,  month = mm, day = dd) 
    return ts.to_julian_date()
bornmonth = 2
bornday = 20
bornyear = 1980
deathmonth = 1
deathday = 1
deathyear = 2023
born = get_julian(bornmonth,bornday,bornyear)
died = get_julian(deathmonth,deathday,deathyear)
julian_age = died - born
print(julian_age/365)
```

Now I want to incorporate this code into a Calculate Field operation in ArcGIS 10.7.  Here is the code block I am using.  The attribute to be populated (age) is a type double.

[image]

Here is the error message I get on execution:

```
Executing: CalculateField "Grave Sites" age (get_julian(!death_mm! , !death_dd! , !DeathDateY! ) - get_julian( !birth_mm!, !birth_dd!, BirthDateY! ))/365.0 PYTHON_9.3 "import pandas\ndef get_julian(mm,dd,yyyy):\n    ts = pandas.Timestamp(year = yyyy,  month = mm, day = dd) \n    return ts.to_julian_date()"
Start Time: Wed May 17 12:05:29 2023
ERROR 000539: Error running expression: (get_julian(1 , 4 , 2020 ) - get_julian( 2, 6, BirthDateY ))/365.0 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<expression>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 3, in get_julian
  File "pandas/tslib.pyx", line 291, in pandas.tslib.Timestamp.__new__ (pandas\tslib.c:9120)
TypeError: __new__() takes at least 2 positional arguments (1 given)

Failed to execute (CalculateField).
Failed at Wed May 17 12:05:29 2023 (Elapsed Time: 0.08 seconds)
```

ArcGIS Code 000539 indicates a type error but all my inputs are floats as in the test code.  I have tried casting all of the inputs to integers with

```
ts = pandas.Timestamp(year = int(yyyy),  month = int(mm), day = int(dd))
```

but this does not change the error message.

Why is my code block throwing this error?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a problem with ArcGIS 10.7 and the Pandas library.  The expression worked just fine in ArcGIS Pro.